# Javers - Select attributes to compare

Tags: javers

Is there any way to compare two objects ONLY select attributes I want? I understand we can use ignore mechanism, but if it is a large object I will need to ignore many attributes, in this cases best option is select ONLY what we want.

Any clue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is use a comparator:

```
    javersBuilder.registerCustomComparator(new JaversClazzCustomizedComparator(), ClazzCustomized.class).build();
```

Internally you could create a equal for each attribute.

Thanks,

Comment: True, that's the only option